# Wordpress installation hiccup

Tags: apache2, php, gedit, wordpress

I am an Ubuntu newbie attempting a wordpress install for a school project, and all was going well until I tried to use gedit to change the wp-config-sample.php

My issue is when I navigate in filesystem to var/www nothing wordpress related pops up. I have wordpress installed on my desktop with what looks like all the files I need there but I am unsure how to move them to the gedit area. This is the set of instructions I was following for reference: http://www.ciss100.com/ubuntu-linux-virtualization/ubuntu-final-projects/lamp-installation/wordpress-installation/

Any help is appreciated, thank you guys!

Comment: So have you edited the file? Or just looked for it?

Comment: `ln -s /usr/share/wordpress /var/www/wordpress` probably failed. The purpose of this is to make a "shortcut" from `/var/www/wordpress` to `/usr/share/wordpress`

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite unclear, but the way I see it your `/var/www` does not contain any wordpress files. This means that the `ln` failed.

Simply run `ln -sf /usr/share/wordpress /var/www/wordpress` to force the link.